# コマンドから VSCode を起動できない

Tags: macos, vscode

以下の参考ページに記載の手順 "対処方法その1" を実施してみましたが、Mac のターミナルから VSCode を起動できません。

**参考にしたページ:**
[【Visual Studio Code】コマンドからVS Codeを起動できない場合 (Mac編)](https://qiita.com/ayatokura/items/69c96306e3dee501e19b)

> **対処方法その1**
>
> 1. VS Codeをいったんアプリケーションから起動する。
> 2. コマンドパレットで Shell と入力し、シェルコマンドのメニューを表示する。
> 3. 「シェルコマンド: PAHT内にVS Codeをインストールします (Shell Command: Install code command in PATH)」を選択する。

また、同じページの "対処方法その2" の方法でやると画像のような状態になります。
読み取り専用なので変更ができない旨の説明があり、先へ進めません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そもそも、なぜ起動するのにコマンドでするかというと、VScodeで修正したファイルをターミナルのgit statusで見ても修正されたと表示されない為です。
何かヒントがあれば教えて頂けると助かります。どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: macOSがCatalina(10.15)で変更する必要があるのはzshのprofileだったりしませんか？ [【macOS】10.15 Catalinaのzshプロファイルに対応する](https://www.yokoweb.net/2019/10/12/macos-catalina-zsh-profile/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。macOS Big Sur11.2.1でしたが、手順通りやってみました。なんら変化はありませんでした。ありがとうございます。VScodeを削除し、ターミナルからxcode-select --installし、ググってxcodebuild -versionで確認が取れましたが、今度はVScodeがMacのどこにもありません。仕方なくHPダウンロードし、インストールしました。元の状態です。

Comment: ここ [Launching from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line) に設定手順が書いてあるようなので、それで出来ないのなら Issue を出してみてはどうでしょう？ それからターミナル？の`git status`で更新状況が見えない件もVSCode関連であれば Issues を探してみるとか、それで無いのなら、そちらの件も Issue を出してみては？

Comment: いろいろ試してみました。https://www.it-swarm.jp.net/ja/xcode/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89xcode%e3%82%92%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95/822930048/%e3%81%ae%e6%89%8b%e9%a0%86%e9%80%9a%e3%82%8a%e3%81%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af/で、インストールはできましたが、ターミナルから起動しませんでした。やむ無く、外部VScodeをインストールし、code .で騙し騙しやっていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Codeの本体`code`のある場所をPATHに追加してください。